# How to pass a prop to {children} in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Parent component that acts as a wrapper to its children. How do I pass a prop to a child that will be rendered using the format below?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  const [completeState, setCompleteState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      /* .. code that runs then sets completeState to true */
    setCompleteState(true);
     }, []
  );

  return (
     <section>
       /* 
          how to pass a 'didComplete' prop to children?
           didComplete={completeState}
       */
       {children} // Child component below would be rendered here with the didComplete prop passed in
    </section>

  )
}
```

```
import React from 'react';

const Child = ({ didComplete }) => (<h1>The function completed? {didComplete}</h1>);
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `props.children` is a React *Element*, which is nothing but a plain JS object having the description of what needs to be rendered in the DOM.

To provide additional details, we need to *clone* the existing React Element object and provide the additional details.

To do this we can use the `React.cloneElement` API to pass the additional prop to the `children` :

```
return (
     <section>
       {React.cloneElement(children, {didComplete: completeState})}
    </section>
);
```

Comment: are there any drawbacks of using cloneElement?

Comment: No. No drawbacks!

Comment: Only works with a single, direct child. Will also create further difficulties if using typescript